# django urls.py cannot process the url

Tags: python, django, linux, debian

i am creating a django app, my project name is domain_com and the application name is gallery. The project is mapped to domain.com, so that works, now when i create the urls.py with these redirects its giving me these errors

```
(r'^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'domain_com.gallery.views.edit_page'),
(r'^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$', 'domain_com.gallery.views.save_page'),
(r'^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'domain_com.gallery.views.view_page')
```

error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in domain_com.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 

^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$ 
^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$ 
^domain_com/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$ 
The current URL, edit, didn't match any of these.
```

any idea where the problem is? my intial install of django worked after create the application, so i am sure its the urls.py

this is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.domain.com/htdocs/
ErrorLog /var/www/www.domain.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/www.domain.com/logs/access.log combined
SetHandler mod_python
PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
PythonPath sys.path+['/var/app/virtual/']
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE domain_com.settings
SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
<Location "/gallery/">
SetHandler None
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's the url you're visiting? domain.com/domain_com/edit? Sure you're not missing on the page name?

Comment: i am testing using http://www.domain.com/edit

Comment: mod_python is dead and Django support is set to be removed in 1.5. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modpython/ You should switch to mod_wsgi if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after updated my answer:

try this:

```
(r'^/edit/(?P<page_name>\w+)$', 'gallery.views.edit_page'),
(r'^/save/(?P<page_name>\w+)$', 'gallery.views.save_page'),
(r'^/(?P<page_name>\w+)$', 'gallery.views.view_page')
```

While `urls.py` is root folder of your application.

Then if you visit:

http://domain.com/edit/page1

it should work

Comment: still gives 404 error http://www.domain.com/edit/page_name1 or whatever i put at edit/pagenames

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6295/discussion-between-krisdigitx-and-moguzalp)

Comment: 1) make sure your app is in the installed apps in settings.py 2) in the root urls.py make sure u include your apps urls.py 3) then use relative urls in your apps urls.py

Answer (score 3):

You have made a complicated URL of the form `http://domain.com/domain_com/page_name/edit/`. Yet you're testing with the URL `http://domain.com/edit`. Obviously, those don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Set up both your main root urls to include the urls of your apps: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs